# Unexpected value 'RoundProgressModule' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation

Tags: angular, webpack-3, typescript2.4

After Updating the packages from angular4 to angular5.0 and angular-svg-round-progressbar1.2.0. It throws error in Browser console

**Unexpected value 'RoundProgressModule' imported by the module 'AppModule'.

Please add a @NgModule annotation**.

See the below code:

**.html**

```
 <round-progress [color]="'orange'"
                        [current]="idleCountdown" [max]="100" [radius]="50"></round-progress>
```

**.ts**

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
    styleUrls: [],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class DashBoard implements OnInit {
 Countdown: number;

  ngOnInit() {

  this.idleCountdown = 40;
  }    
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';  
import { RoundProgressModule } from 'angular-svg-round-progressbar';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { routing } from './app.routing';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        RouterModule,
        MaterialModule,
        RoundProgressModule
        ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        ], 
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**Packages.json**

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.0.0-rc0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^5.0.0-rc0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
    "angular-svg-round-progressbar": "^1.2.0"
    }
```

Comment: post the code for RoundProgressModule

Comment: @Sajeetharan i have post the code for RoundProgressModule

Comment: where ? i dont see it. RoundProgressModule .ts

Comment: I has referred this link please check it https://github.com/crisbeto/angular-svg-round-progressbar

Comment: @Sajeetharan if i downgrade the angular packages to 4.3.6 version. It work's fine. After updating packages to 4.4.0-RC.0 it throws error.

Comment: I've seen this same type of error when trying to add modules, I'm starting to guess it might be some sort of compatibility issue when trying to use an Angular 2 component with an Angular 4 component.

Comment: @haakon.io after updating the packages to latest version it worked fine